# Fire redux dispatch in custom onclick event

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've hunted around but can't seem to find 9or understand) how to achieve this.

I have a button that fires an event on click

```
<button onClick={TestClick}>Click Me </button>
```

the TestClick event reads as:

```
let TestClick = (e) => {
    const Dispatch = useDispatch();
    let Num = Math.random()*10;
    Dispatch(Increment(num));
};
```

This triggers `Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.` error.

How do I dispatch within a user function?

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from './actions';

    let TestClick = () => {
        const dispatch = useDispatch();
        let Num = Math.random() * 10;
        dispatch(increment(Num));
    };

function App() {
    const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isLogged);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(5))}>+</button>
            <button onClick={() => TestClick()}>+Random</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>-</button>
            {isLoggedIn ? <h3>Valueable info</h3> : ''}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you check [Breaking the Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html)

Comment: @huMptyduMpty so I'm breaking the hook rule because I'm firing it within an event handler, so how can I remdy this as the information generated is contained in the event handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use hooks outside of React components or another hook.

Two solutions:

```js
const useTestClick = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let num = Math.random() * 10;
  return () => dispatch(increment(num));
};

function App() {
  const testClick = useTestClick()

  /* ... */

  <button onClick={testClick}>+Random</button>
```

```
function App() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const testClick = useCallback(() => {
    let num = Math.random() * 10;
    return () => dispatch(increment(num));
  }, [])

  /* ... */

  <button onClick={testClick}>+Random</button>
```

Comment: The first snippet worked, couldn't get the second to work, no errors just didn't do anything

Comment: @Neo I had a bug  I forgot the callback on return. I think. I hope. I haven't used callbacks in a whiiiile.

Comment: I'm trying something similar with useContext and useReducer but doing something like   return () => dispatch(increment(num));
 won't actually dispatch the action and the state will be left unchanged. Is there something different one should do when not using  useDispatch but instead using const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { age: 42 });

Answer (score 1):

Move the `TestClick` inside the comnponent. And to keep the handler reference from changing on each render, use `useCallback`

```
import { useCallback, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { increment, decrement } from './actions';

function App() {
    const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter);
    const isLoggedIn = useSelector((state) => state.isLogged);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const TestClick = useCallback(() => {
        let Num = Math.random() * 10;
        dispatch(increment(Num));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <h1>Counter {counter}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(increment(5))}>+</button>
            <button onClick={TestClick}>+Random</button>
            <button onClick={() => dispatch(decrement())}>-</button>
            {isLoggedIn ? <h3>Valueable info</h3> : ''}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```